# Bootstrap carousel caption not responsive? (HTML, CSS)

Tags: html, css, responsive, caption

I am trying to make a responsive Carousel with a caption that contains a p-tag and a h3-tag. Looks good but whenever I resize my window to check how it would look on mobile devices the h3 and p-tags barely adjust.

How can I make my caption responsive? I'll post the code below so that you can try it out. My html and CSS.

```css
.carousel-caption {
    width: 50%;
    top: 20%;
    text-align: left;
}

.carousel-caption h3{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 4em;
    text-align:left;
}

.carousel-caption p{
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align:left;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<section class="jsslider" id="home">
  <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="3"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="4"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="5"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active"> <img class="d-block w-100" src="fotos/Slider1.jpg" alt="ersteSlide">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>So groß wie ein halber Fußballfeld.
          </h3>
          <p>Große Waldbrände entsprechen ungefähr einer größe von einem halben Fußballfeld. </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item"> <img class="d-block w-100" src="fotos/slider2.jpg" alt="zweiteSlide">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>So groß wie ein halber Fußballfeld.
          </h3>
          <p>Große Waldbrände entsprechen ungefähr einer größe von einem halben Fußballfeld. </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item"> 
       <img class="d-block w-100" src="fotos/slider3.jpg" alt="dritteSlide">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>So groß wie ein halber Fußballfeld.
          </h3>
          <p>Große Waldbrände entsprechen ungefähr einer größe von einem halben Fußballfeld. </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item"> <img class="d-block w-100" src="fotos/slider4.jpg" alt="vierteSlide">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>So groß wie ein halber Fußballfeld.
          </h3>
          <p>Große Waldbrände entsprechen ungefähr einer größe von einem halben Fußballfeld. </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item"> <img class="d-block w-100" src="fotos/slider5.jpg" alt="fuenfteSlide">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>So groß wie ein halber Fußballfeld.
          </h3>
          <p>Große Waldbrände entsprechen ungefähr einer größe von einem halben Fußballfeld. </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev"> <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">Previous</span> </a> <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next"> <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">Next</span> </a> </div>
</section>
```

Comment: It's hard to tell without a working codepen or jsfiddle, but did you try adding "d-md-block" to "carousel-caption". It's also in the example at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/

Comment: oh and also add "left: 15%; right: 15%" or similar to the .carousel-caption. If it doesn't work, please throw together a working live-example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set font-size on bootstrap's break points. Example:

```
.carousel-caption h3 {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.2em; /* small size since this is the default in Bootstrap */
    text-align:left;
}

.carousel-caption p {
    font-size: 1em; /* small size since this is the default in Bootstrap */
    text-align:left;
}
@media (min-width: 576px) { // Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up)
  .carousel-caption h3 { font-size: 1.3em;}
  .carousel-caption p {font-size: 1.1em;}  
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {// Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up)
  .carousel-caption h3 { font-size: 1.4em;}
  .carousel-caption p {font-size: 1.2em;}  
}
@media (min-width: 992px) { // Large devices (desktops, 992px and up)
  .carousel-caption h3 { font-size: 1.5em;}
  .carousel-caption p {font-size: 1.3em;}  
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) { // Extra large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up)
  .carousel-caption h3 { font-size: 1.6em;}
  .carousel-caption p {font-size: 1.4em;}  
}
```

Of course this is just an example. Take a look [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/) and 
hope that helps.